# Nested Function in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Iam using an third party js **D3js**. My function structure looks like

```
a(){
      function nested1(){
        
      }
      function nested2(){

      }

}


b(){



}
```

I can call the nested function from nested function. But Iam not able to call the b() from nested function. `this` param not working inside the nested function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of lexical scope in JS.

For calling the function `b` from nested function you need to use **FAT ARROW**

```
a() { () => {
 this.b();   
}
```

If you want to give a name to function then it should be :

```
a() {
    let nested1 = () => {this.b()}
}
```

Comment: It's just an "arrow function", not a BIG FAT ARROW function. Also, it's nothing to do with LWC, this is a plain JavaScript feature.

Comment: Yeah, saw the name in one of the js blogs. So just wrote it.

Comment: In some languages, there's little arrows (`->`) to not confuse it with "greater or equals" (`=>`).

Comment: @NagendraSingh I tried, but nested function not even called

Comment: That is very weird, can you update your question with your updated code.